# How do I update listview with button when list is gotten from a directorychooser?

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I am a beginner programmer and I made a texteditor with a listview.

You can load a folder with your text files in the textview.
the problem I'm having is that I can't get the list to update after you save a file in the same folder.

I made a button for updating the list but I can't get it to work. I tried to remove and add the list again
with **.clear** and **.setAll** but it just removes the list. 
[Example of how to program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F82wF.png)

Can someone help me to get the list to update when you push the "Refresh list" button?

Here is my code :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    //Create list with files
    ObservableList files = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView list = new ListView(files);
    Button c = new Button("Load Folder");
    c.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
            dc.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            File choice = dc.showDialog(primaryStage);
            if (choice == null || !choice.isDirectory()) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setHeaderText("Could not open directory");
                alert.setContentText("The file is invalid.");

                alert.showAndWait();
            }
            assert choice != null;
            File[] selectedFiles = choice.listFiles();
            files.removeAll(files);
            files.addAll(selectedFiles);
            list.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<File>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(File file, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(file, empty);
                    setText(file == null ? null : file.getName());
                }
            });
        }
    });


    // MENUS
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    Menu menuFile = new Menu("File");
    Menu help = new Menu("help");

    //Menu contents
    // Menu FILE
    MenuItem newfile = new MenuItem("New");
    MenuItem open = new MenuItem("Open");
    MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save");
    MenuItem export = new MenuItem("Export to txt");
    MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");

    newfile.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.N, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
    open.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.O, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
    save.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
    export.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.E, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
    exit.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.W, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));


    //Menu HELP
    MenuItem about = new MenuItem("About J4hN0te");


    //Adding Menus in the box
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuFile, help);
    menuFile.getItems().addAll(newfile, open, save, export, exit);
    help.getItems().addAll(about);


    //CREATE TEXTEDITOR
    final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
    htmlEditor.setPrefHeight(500);
    htmlEditor.setPrefWidth(600);


    //SCROLLIST
    ScrollPane scrollpane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollpane.getStyleClass().add("noborder-scroll-pane");
    scrollpane.setContent(htmlEditor);
    scrollpane.setFitToHeight(true);


    // ABOUT WINDOW
    String programName = "J4hN0te";
    String version = "1.0 alpha";
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Om programmet");
    alert.setHeaderText(programName + " - Version " + version + "\nEtt program skapat i kursen \"Intro Javaprogrammering\"\nYrkesAkademin Sundsvall - HT2019");
    alert.setContentText("Vi som gjort programmet är:\n André Pähn \n Fredrik Lax");


    // CREATE NEW FILE
    newfile.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
        htmlEditor.setHtmlText("");
    });

    //OPEN FILE
    open.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.getExtensionFilters()
                .addAll(
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".rtf files (*.rtf)", "*.rtf"),
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".html files (*.html)", "*.html"));
        File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(String.valueOf(selectedFile))))) {

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                lines.add(line);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        lines.forEach(htmlEditor::setHtmlText);
    });

    // EXPORT FILE TO TXT
    export.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.getExtensionFilters()
                .addAll(
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".txt files (*.txt)", "*.txt"));
        File savefile = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
        try {
            String htmlString = htmlEditor.getHtmlText();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString);
            final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(htmlString.length());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                matcher.appendReplacement(sb, System.lineSeparator());
            }
            matcher.appendTail(sb);
            String fixedHtmlString = sb.toString().trim().replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(savefile);
            fw.write(fixedHtmlString);

            fw.close();


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    });

    //Save file to RTF or HTML
    save.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.getExtensionFilters()
                .addAll(
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".rtf files (*.rtf)", "*.rtf"),
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".html files (*.html)", "*.html"));
        File savefile = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(savefile);
            fw.write(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());

            fw.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // EXIT PROGRAM
    exit.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
        System.exit(1);
    });

    // Open About window
    about.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> alert.showAndWait());

    //OPEN FILE IN EDITOR WITH DOUBLE CLICK
    list.setOnMouseClicked((EventHandler<MouseEvent>) mouseEvent -> {
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
            File item = (File) list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(String.valueOf(item))))) {

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    lines.add(line);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            lines.forEach(htmlEditor::setHtmlText);
        }
    });

    // BUTTON FOR UPDATING THE LIST
    Button refresh = new Button("Refresh List");
    refresh.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            files.clear();
            files.setAll();
        }
    });


    //GENERAL WINDOW SETTINGS
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    SplitPane split = new SplitPane();
    split.setDividerPositions(0.3);
    split.getItems().add(list);
    split.getItems().add(htmlEditor);
    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.getChildren().add(c);
    hb.getChildren().add(refresh);

    BorderPane borderpane = new BorderPane();
    borderpane.setTop(menuBar);
    borderpane.setCenter(split);
    borderpane.setLeft(list);
    borderpane.setRight(htmlEditor);
    borderpane.setBottom(hb);


    stackPane.getChildren().add(borderpane);

    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);

    primaryStage.setTitle("J4hN0te");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(900);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(700);
    primaryStage.show();

  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to always comment your code in English even if you believe it will only be used by yourself, sometimes you just need to share it.

Comment: Thanks! I Changed it to English now :)

Comment: Great, good luck with your class.

Comment: Pay close attention the example in [the contract of the Cell.updateItem method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem%28T,boolean%29).

Comment: `setAll` is a varargs method you pass all the objects to that should be in the list after the call. You've already cleared the list though... Also simply asuming the directory being non-`null` is not a good idea. Choosing to close the chooser without selecting something is kind of an expected behaviour; you should be able to deal with this kind of input too. `assert` is usually simply ignored when you compile your release version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things you need to change in your code.

1. You need to create a File object to store the selected folder, so
   you can reload it every time you need to refresh.
2. In the setOnAction() method of the refresh button you call the
   setAll() method of files with no arguments. This methods clears the
   list and adds all the elements given. That's why the list is empty
   every time you refresh.

Now the setOnAction() method of the refresh button would be like
    this:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    files.setAll(directory.listFiles());
}
```

Comment: Why is a refresh button needed?  What’s wrong with calling `choice.listFiles()` after the user has selected a directory and accepted (closed) the file dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to keep up with the current directory that is loaded into the list view. Follow `currentFolderLoaded` in the code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main extends Application
{

    File currentFolderLoaded = null;//Use to keep track of current folder loaded in ListView

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {

        //Create list with files
        ObservableList files = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView list = new ListView(files);
        Button c = new Button("Load Folder");
        c.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
                dc.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                File choice = dc.showDialog(primaryStage);                
                if (choice == null || !choice.isDirectory()) {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                    alert.setHeaderText("Could not open directory");
                    alert.setContentText("The file is invalid.");

                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
                assert choice != null;
                currentFolderLoaded = new File(choice.getAbsolutePath());//Assign the currently loaded folder to this variable
                File[] selectedFiles = choice.listFiles();
                files.removeAll(files);
                files.addAll(selectedFiles);
                list.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<File>()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(File file, boolean empty)
                    {
                        super.updateItem(file, empty);
                        setText(file == null ? null : file.getName());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // MENUS
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu menuFile = new Menu("File");
        Menu help = new Menu("help");

        //Menu contents
        // Menu FILE
        MenuItem newfile = new MenuItem("New");
        MenuItem open = new MenuItem("Open");
        MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save");
        MenuItem export = new MenuItem("Export to txt");
        MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");

        newfile.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.N, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
        open.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.O, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
        save.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
        export.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.E, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
        exit.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.W, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));

        //Menu HELP
        MenuItem about = new MenuItem("About J4hN0te");

        //Adding Menus in the box
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuFile, help);
        menuFile.getItems().addAll(newfile, open, save, export, exit);
        help.getItems().addAll(about);

        //CREATE TEXTEDITOR
        final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
        htmlEditor.setPrefHeight(500);
        htmlEditor.setPrefWidth(600);

        //SCROLLIST
        ScrollPane scrollpane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollpane.getStyleClass().add("noborder-scroll-pane");
        scrollpane.setContent(htmlEditor);
        scrollpane.setFitToHeight(true);

        // ABOUT WINDOW
        String programName = "J4hN0te";
        String version = "1.0 alpha";
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Om programmet");
        alert.setHeaderText(programName + " - Version " + version + "\nEtt program skapat i kursen \"Intro Javaprogrammering\"\nYrkesAkademin Sundsvall - HT2019");
        alert.setContentText("Vi som gjort programmet är:\n André Pähn \n Fredrik Lax");

        // CREATE NEW FILE
        newfile.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
            htmlEditor.setHtmlText("");
        });

        //OPEN FILE
        open.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {

            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            fc.getExtensionFilters()
                    .addAll(
                            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".rtf files (*.rtf)", "*.rtf"),
                            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".html files (*.html)", "*.html"));
            File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(String.valueOf(selectedFile))))) {

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            lines.forEach(htmlEditor::setHtmlText);
        });

        // EXPORT FILE TO TXT
        export.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            fc.getExtensionFilters()
                    .addAll(
                            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".txt files (*.txt)", "*.txt"));
            File savefile = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
            try {
                String htmlString = htmlEditor.getHtmlText();
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString);
                final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(htmlString.length());
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, System.lineSeparator());
                }
                matcher.appendTail(sb);
                String fixedHtmlString = sb.toString().trim().replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(savefile);
                fw.write(fixedHtmlString);

                fw.close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        });

        //Save file to RTF or HTML
        save.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            fc.getExtensionFilters()
                    .addAll(
                            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".rtf files (*.rtf)", "*.rtf"),
                            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(".html files (*.html)", "*.html"));
            File savefile = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
            try {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(savefile);
                fw.write(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());

                fw.close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        });

        // EXIT PROGRAM
        exit.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> {
            System.exit(1);
        });

        // Open About window
        about.setOnAction(ActionEvent -> alert.showAndWait());

        //OPEN FILE IN EDITOR WITH DOUBLE CLICK
        list.setOnMouseClicked((EventHandler<MouseEvent>) mouseEvent -> {
            if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
                File item = (File) list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(String.valueOf(item))))) {

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        lines.add(line);
                    }

                }
                catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                lines.forEach(htmlEditor::setHtmlText);
            }
        });

        // BUTTON FOR UPDATING THE LIST
        Button refresh = new Button("Refresh List");
        refresh.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Refresh the currently loaded folder
                if(currentFolderLoaded != null)
                {
                    File[] selectedFiles = currentFolderLoaded.listFiles();
                    files.setAll(selectedFiles);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("NO DIRECTORY CHOSEN!");
                }
            }
        });

        //GENERAL WINDOW SETTINGS
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        SplitPane split = new SplitPane();
        split.setDividerPositions(0.3);
        split.getItems().add(list);
        split.getItems().add(htmlEditor);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().add(c);
        hb.getChildren().add(refresh);

        BorderPane borderpane = new BorderPane();
        borderpane.setTop(menuBar);
        borderpane.setCenter(split);
        borderpane.setLeft(list);
        borderpane.setRight(htmlEditor);
        borderpane.setBottom(hb);

        stackPane.getChildren().add(borderpane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("J4hN0te");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(900);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(700);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```